# cross and nought game and find the heuristic function

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I have the artificial intelligence course this semester and I have to hand in an AI project...

since I do not have any good idea for project that I want to choose I decided to use the simplest one for practice to get a more solid idea:  cross and nought game

But even in this game I need a heuristic function to estimate each game branch for example if I have that function it is easy to estimate the best next move but now the problem is how can I find that function?(I need an indication to find my way and Maybe now I am not on a right track if yes can you guide me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pick a game where it makes more sense to use a heuristic function. In tic-tac-toe you can calculate all the way to the end and so no heuristic function needs to be used. In addition, there is no score, only a win condition, making heuristics less useful.

Try something like [Reversi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi). A good heuristic function in that games would be how many pieces are your color.

If you really want a heuristics function for tic-tac-toe, why not try how many different ways you have 2 of your symbol on a line minus how many ways your opponent has two on a line. Won't really be very smart, but, whatever. Don't forget to make a win position worth more than any other position.

Comment: is tic-tac-toe the same game as noughts and crosses? [or cross and nought as the original poster wrote it]

Comment: I think they are the same

Comment: Can you please introduce me an AI topic(game or whatever) that the following AI algorithms BFS or A* or DFS or... can be well fitted in that? (I think if I have a good scenario I can solve this confusion that I am dealing with)

Comment: For BFS or A* or DFS it is best to be trying to find a solution, and not be in a game type of environment with two different competitor. For example, solving a maze is a great use for BFS, A* and DFS.